# BIOS update on Asus without battery

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, battery

I have an Asus laptop (model ASUS ROG zephyrus S GX531GWR) running GNU/Linux (Debian Stretch) with a non-functional battery and I want to update the BIOS. How can I update the BIOS without WinFlash and EasyFlash?

I don't use Windows, so I can't use the WinFlash utility from Asus
the battery doesn't work, so I can't use EasyFlash (it requires a battery charged to at least 20%)
I'm used to updating the BIOS using FreeDOS. This works fine when the BIOS update is an executable file. However, the BIOS from Asus are displayed as data files (I downloaded GX531GWR-AS.305).

Edit: The reason for updating the BIOS is that it recognizes the battery. The battery (which is not removable) has always worked fine. When I changed the OS, it stopped working. This is not a problem in Linux, even after reinstalling Windows and the battery problem remains. The reported fix is to update the BIOS, which fixes this before changing the OS again.

Comment: Running a laptop with a non-functioning battery presents a host of problems that you can google. It looks like you can replace the battery for $50-75 US from amazon. The replacement is not as simple as on other laptops but it doesn't look difficult. If you're running a gaming laptop I would go with the replacement.

Comment: Image the hard drive, Install windows and then upgrade bios, after it is successful, apply the image you made earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Flash any / most Asus motherboard Bios in DOS with USB tutorial - Intel AMD roll back](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?99490-Flash-any-most-Asus-motherboard-Bios-in-DOS-with-USB-tutorial-Intel-AMD-roll-back)
contains links and a video explaining the use of the linked tools.

The method that is outlined seems to have worked for some participants,
but use extreme caution if you decide to employ it.

The poster assumed that you are on Windows, so you may need to adapt
it to your use. Perhaps WINE will be helpful here.